# Find the distance from the center of the polygon to this line.

Tags: geometry

For reference
The sum of the perpendiculars drawn by the vertices of a regular hexagon a
an outer line is 18.Find the distance from the center of the polygon to this line.

my progress:

$O_1O = x=?$
We need to find: $(F_1F_2+FF_2)+(A_2A_1+AA_2)+(E_2E_1)+(B_2B_1+BB_2)+(D_1D_2)+(CC_2+C_2C_1) = 18$

or

$(FF_1)+(AA_1)+(E_1E_2)+(BB_1)+(D_1D_2)+(CC_1)=18$

I managed to draw the picture. I drew some auxiliary lines,
Heights will be parallel.
We have several similar triangles internally to the triangle $VC_1C_2$.
But I couldn't find the relationship to find the sum of the heights. (Answer: x=3)

[image]

Comment: Hint: The distance to center is the average of the distances (to the line) for any pair of "opposite" vertices of the hexagon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{AA_1+DD_2}{2}=d =2d(I)\\ 
\frac{E_1E_2+B_1B}{2}=d=2d(II)\\ 
\frac{FF_1+CC_1}{2}=d=2d(III)\\
Sum (I+II+III) =18\rightarrow 6d = 18 \therefore \boxed{\color{red}d = 3}  $

Answer (score 1):

Due to vector symmetry for any regular n- sided polygon average of sum of projections is from the center of the polygon:

$$ \bar p =\dfrac{\Sigma p}{n} =\dfrac{18}{6} =3.$$

Proof : Vector sum of sides =0, the above is a general relation.